# How to use definitions (define variable) in include

Tags: php

I am trying to create some "config.php" where I will have defined global variables, like default path to project. How can I use this defined variable in include?

My config.php:

```
$path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/docme/";

require_once "resources/scripts/pdo.php";

ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
date_default_timezone_set( "Europe/Prague" );

//Nastavení konstant webu
define('DB_NAME', 'project');
define('DB_USER', 'root');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'pswd');
define('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1');
define('SITETITLE', 'DocMe!');
define('PATH', $path);
```

And now I need to use the PATH variable in include, is it even possible?

```
<?php
   require_once "config.php";
   include_once PATH."/index.php";
?>
```

Okay sorry here is the problem I didn't realize it's actually problem somewhere else. On localhost it's working fine, at website (live) it's not working, cuz   $path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] = returns me only "/".

Comment: what seems to be the problem with your code?

Comment: please specify the problem of the code so people can help you

Comment: Yes it's working on localhost, but why it's not working the $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] on live website? It returns me only "/" not something like "http://student.sps-prosek.cz/....", is it better to use  $path = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST''] ?

Comment: Most of the `$_SERVER` variables need to be provided by your cgi connection to PHP so it depends on the server. You know where `config.php` is located compared to your root of your server, so just do `__DIR__ . '/../../../../'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Yes it's working on localhost, but why it's not working the $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] on live website? It returns me only "/" not something like "student.sps-prosek.cz/....";, is it better to use $path = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST''] ?"

I understand your problem, the problem is when you deploy to a server the url will change.

try this code

```
<?php

define('PROJECT_BASE_FOLDER'    , substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 0, 8) == '/sample/' ? '/sample/' : '');
//sample is the name of the folder. the 0 to 8 is how many char your project name has including the '/'

define('PROJECT_FOLDER'         , substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 0, 8) == '/sample/' ? '' : '');
define('HTTP'                   , 'http://');
define('BASE_PATH'              , $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . PROJECT_BASE_FOLDER . PROJECT_FOLDER);

define('SITE_URL'               , HTTP . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . str_replace($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/', '', BASE_PATH));
// or ':8080/' is the port you are using in your local machine
define('SITE_URL'               , HTTP . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . ':8080/' . str_replace($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/', '', BASE_PATH));
```

therefore in your code you will use

```
<?php
   require_once "config.php";
   include_once BASE_PATH ."/index.php";
?>
```

This should work as I am using this logic so that I will not have to change the directory every time I need to deploy to a server.

Comment: BASE_PATH returns "/", the SITE_URL returns "http://student.sps-prosek.cz/" and the project is in "http://student.sps-prosek.cz/~kocvaja14/projectFolder/ can I add a string after that SITE_URL?

Comment: basically, BASE_PATH is everything after "student.sps-prosek.cz/~kocvaja14/projectFolder/"

so basically in your local machine, BASE_PATH is everything after http://localhost:8080/

so no matter in what server you deploy, the BASE_PATH will be the / of your project folder.

and if needed yes you can add something in the site URL

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use PATH /*constant*/ at any file which include your config.php file

but this is something weired for include index.php

> include_once PATH."/index.php";

Comment: Yes sorry it's actually working I didn't notice that error is in  $path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . It returns me only "/" and not "http://student.sps-prosek.cz/...", it works only on localhost